# Android Dev. - I'm designing an app that will require sign-ups with a college email, but all i find are things for Google+. Any suggestions?

Tags: android, google-plus

Like how I tried to effectively word in the title, my issue with Sign-ups and log-ins for my application is that it would work best with a college email, as it's an app designed for college campuses, but I can only find APIs and information regarding the Google+ sign-up that is everywhere.

For instance, an app like Kik does not require a Google+ sign-in and you can make your account however you like, but I've not found any information on how to go about creating a sign-in like that. The only substantial information regarding sign-ups/log-ins I've found are for the Google+ API.

The only other thing i thought of was using the Google+ sign-in to verify the person, and then having something in the settings to enter and save the college email for the uses it'll have.

Would any of you have thoughts on this? I'd prefer not to do the latter simply because it requires more for set-up of the app on the users part (which isn't ideal) to use it's full functionality, but I don't really see any other way of doing it at this point.

Comment: google some more. there are many alternatives including one identity library by google.

Comment: Can't you just do the normal sign in process and if their email doesn't end in `.edu` show them an error?

Comment: Zig, i've tried finding what you said and still, all i'm getting are Google+ sign-ins, both from google and on the Android Development pages. 

Abraham, i don't know what the normal sign in process is, the only sign-in process i've found in total is the Google+ sign-in.